# How can change a text on a label in COMPONENTS PAGE when using MUI2 for NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to add a link somewhere on the components page. I tried the method presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318974/how-can-i-modify-the-text-in-the-mui-welcome-page-when-using-mui2-for-nsis), while it is indeed working for the WELCOME PAGE, it causes the installer to crash when I'm adding it to the components page.

The thing I want to add is a text that contains an underlined blue word which opens a url on the default browser when clicked on. I want to add it to the existing components page.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you post the code that crashes, that will help to get a better answer. Also the question you've linked to is about modifying the text of existing label and you seem to want to add a new label which will require a different solution.

Comment: actually I've just solved this using some help from the nsis forum, I'll add it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using some help from the nsis forum the relevant links are:

[Add Link to Components Page](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=320113) and [How to customize an existing MUI2 page (components)](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?p=2808601#post2808601)

The main issue is that in contrast to welcome/finish page, the components page is not a nsDialog page. In order to dynamically add a label we have to use User32::CreateWindowEx. I used the resource hacker to add a static label in order to get its position and use that as a guide for the new label I added (It's all explained in the links...)

Comment: You link for "Add Link to Components Page" is broken.