# Changing the Label Text Dynmically in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to create a page with labels showing the text dynamically while the page loading. Actually I have created the page (page1.ini) using NSIS Editor. Created the labels with default text using editor.
  I want to change the label text when the page loads.

I have used the following option

```
!insertmacro INSTALLOPTIONS_WRITE "page1.ini" "Field 10" "Text" "Stopping..."
```

But it is not working for me... May I know what mistake I have done in this and also want to know how to change the text for controls which are created in editors...

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706477/how-can-change-a-text-on-a-label-in-components-page-when-using-mui2-for-nsis

Comment: What does while the page loading mean? Are you doing some time consuming operation in the show callback?

Comment: Try to switch to nsDialogs. They offer more possibilities and you can set texts dynamically with WM_ messages.

Comment: For each and every page there is a function defined.... In that function only we are setting the page contents... I have put the code above in at the end of previous page function, so while the current page loading it was updated... Its working fine for me now... Thank you for all your suggestions.. :)