# NSIS: get a text from the internet and put in "BrandingText"

Tags: nsis

I would like to add a text from an online text file [link](https://valeo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/versao.txt) and insert it the following way:

```
BrandingText "14.05.01"
```

or

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "14.05.01"
```

Does NSIS offers this possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I use the [inetc plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) to access a file from a website:

```
#get txt file (silently)
inetc::get /NOCANCEL /SILENT "https://valeo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/versao.txt" "$TEMP\versao.txt" /end
#you may check the return value with: 'Pop $0' and 'StrCmp $0 "OK" 0 Error'
#read file content
FileOpen $4 "$TEMP\versao.txt" r
# read until the end of line and save it to $1
FileRead $4 $1 
#close the file
FileClose $4 
# Now do what you want with $1
```

**UPDATE:**

Yes this code goes into a function. But this is no problem, just follow the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318974/how-can-i-modify-the-text-in-the-mui-welcome-page-when-using-mui2-for-nsis).

Comment: How to use this code if the BrandingText can not be within Section or Function.

And the above code can not appear outside Section or Function?